# Why does the YouTube search API with `channelId` specified return videos from other channels?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am querying the YouTube API to search for videos from a particular channel, with a given query.

For example:

- channelId: `UCIG1k8umaCIIrujZPzZPIMA` ("Made by Google" channel)
- query: `town hall`

Sample query, as taken from the [YouTube API dashboard:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

```bash
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCIG1k8umaCIIrujZPzZPIMA&q=town%20hall&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

This produces the following results:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "s6StXaHbEt-uwoGClbHgkFWOb1A",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "GB",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 10699,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "K_bX_NIF7PuKSUGdsbE8nP9R35c",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "zm4HLTm9n9I"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-10-10T04:24:44Z",
        "channelId": "UCL_A4jkwvKuMyToAPy3FQKQ",
        "title": "Virtual Town Hall: The Conflict in the Middle East",
        "description": "CFR President Michael Froman leads a town hall discussion with CFR Fellows and members on the current crisis in the Middle ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zm4HLTm9n9I/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zm4HLTm9n9I/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zm4HLTm9n9I/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Council on Foreign Relations",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-10-10T04:24:44Z"
      }
    },
    ...etc
```

Notice that the first video is from a completely different channel, with a different channel id.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the API broken?

Comment: Some additional context - I first used this API 4 weeks ago, and everything worked fine. So this does seem like a regression.

Additionally, I just tried using the search term `town` (instead of `town hall`) and the results do not include other channels. So seems like the issue is around using a space in the query?

Comment: By searching `town hall` what video from channel `UCIG1k8umaCIIrujZPzZPIMA` you thought would come first?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison `town hall` was from my application, but I switched the `channelId` to a different one for privacy. So it may not make the best example.

In my case, where `town hall` is a very common term for this particular channel, instead of there being ~100 results, there were ~11,000+ which mostly was other channels.

Comment: Then may you give an ad hoc example that isn't was you expect?